# Validate: Only letters, numbers and -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I would like to validate my users, so they can only use a-z and - in their username.

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /[a-z]/
```

However this rule also allows spaces ._@

```
Username should use only letters, numbers, spaces, and .-_@ please.
```

Any ideas?

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Comment: This is what I came up with: validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[-a-z\d_]+$/

Comment: When you have an answer that solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 18):

You may need to say the whole string must match:

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[-a-z]+$/
```

You may also need to replace ^ with \A and $ with \Z, if you don't want to match a newline at the start/end. (thanks to [BaroqueBobcat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120138/baroquebobcat))

Appending an i will cause it to match in a case-insensitive manner. (thanks to [Omar Qureshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84018/omar-qureshi)).

(I also originally left off the `+`: thanks to [Chuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50742/chuck))

Comment: agreed but as /^[-a-z]$/i for case insensitivity

Comment: You example always returns invalid :/

Comment: test it in irb .. re = /^[-a-z]$/i; "foo" =~ re

Comment: It needs to be `/^[-a-z]+$/` (with an `i` after the second slash if you want it case-insensitive). Without a +, you're saying it has to be exactly one character long.

Comment: ^ and $ match the beginnings and ends of lines. To ensure no newlines use \A \Z which match the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @CanCeylan You should just be able to have a space after the z.

Answer (score 12):

More complex solution but reusable and with more fine grained error messaging.

**Custom validator:**

*app/validators/username_convention_validator.rb*

```
class UsernameConventionValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, field, value)
    unless value.blank?
      record.errors[field] << "is not alphanumeric (letters, numbers, underscores or periods)" unless value =~ /^[[:alnum:]._-]+$/
      record.errors[field] << "should start with a letter" unless value[0] =~ /[A-Za-z]/
      record.errors[field] << "contains illegal characters" unless value.ascii_only?
    end
  end
end
```

(Notice it does allow ' . - _ ' and doesnt allow non ascii, for completeness sake)

**Usage:**

*app/models/user.rb*

```
validates :name,
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => true,
    :username_convention => true
```

Comment: Nice answer - it goes the extra mile.

Answer (score 4):

The [] may contain several "rules"  so [a-z0-9] gives lowercase letters and numbers

the special character - must go at the start of the rule

Does

```
[-a-z0-9@_.]
```

give the effect you want?

Comment: [-A-Za-z0-9@_.] <-- with uppercase, just in case.

Comment: Hmmm no sorry, it gives me Username should use only letters, numbers, spaces, and .-_@ please.

Answer (score 2):

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[\w\-@]*$/
```

Note the *, which means '0 or more'

Comment: Same problem... spaces and . is still allowed :/

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the regular expression to match all characters your specification states (`\w` covers all alphanumeric characters -- letters and numbers -- and an underscore).

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /[\w \.\-@]+/
```

Comment: Your example is pretty close however the user can still use . and spaces. my.......new      user

Comment: There is no limit here to prevent longer strings matching.  This will match any string that contains at least one of the matched characters.

Answer (score 0):

Validation to allow letters and whole numbers only:
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/