# Input validations on fields in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

When I create a new form in ActiveAdmin, I want validations on my form input fields. But I can't find a related tutorial. I want some fields to accept only alphabets, some only digits , and some should be of specific length.

```
f.input :name, :label => "Title", input_html: { autofocus: true }

f.input :description

f.input :email

f.input :contact_number

f.input :contact_person
```

Comment: HASEEB AHMAD,
did you get a chance to look at my answer? 
Let me know if you have any other question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Answer not only for ActiveAdmin, but for RoR in general]*

You should do it in **model**.

**• For digits only:**

You want your `:contact_number` to be a digit, so your model (e.g. `User`) should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   validates :contact_number, numericality: {only_integer: true}

end
```

**• For min. 5 characters:**

If description for example must be at least 5 characters it will be:

```
validates_length_of :description, minimum: 5
```

**• For letters only:**

```
validates_format_of :name, with: /^[-a-z]+$/
```

(details about reg. expressions --> [Validate: Only letters, numbers and -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136049/validate-only-letters-numbers-and) )

*Additional info:*

If your form don't pass model validation it will return alert about wrong argument (which is accessible in `flash[:alert]` array).

More about it in:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#validations

Comment: > Answer not only for ActiveAdmin.
   Where is the answer for active admin form validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the validations defined in your corresponding Model class.
[See the official documentation for Rails validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

`ActiveAdmin` will pick it up when you try to create/edit/update objects of that model if you have Rails standard validations or even custom validations defined in your Model class.

For example, for your email validation, you can have this in your model:

```
 validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
```

Then, when you try to create/save an object through ActiveAdmin, it will show you error if the email is not in the correct format.

So, you have to define all of your validations (for all the fields that you want) in your model. That's it!

And, to display a list of all validation errors, you have to do:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
  # ...
end
```

#### Update

Add these validations to your Model class:

```
validates_presence_of :description
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i 
validates :contact_number, :presence => {:message => 'hello world, bad operation!'},
                     :numericality => true,
                     :length => { :minimum => 10, :maximum => 15 }
```

These are Rails standard validations. You can add custom validations to your model too.

For example, if you want to add a custom validation for the `username`, you can define that like this:

```
validate :username_must_be_valid
```

And, then define the custom validator method `username_must_be_valid` in the same model class like this:

```
  private

  def username_must_be_valid
    errors.add(:username, 'must be present') if username.blank? && provider.blank?
  end
```